# "map: vt01 => fb0" - what is that?

Tags: login, startup, console, raspbian

At startup of Rasbian on Raspberry PI, when console asks for login I can see the following text:

`map: vt01 => fb0`

1. What does that mean?
2. How can I disable it? (hide this message, I would only like to see my welcome text there)

Regards,
AW

Comment: it means the first virtual terminal is mapped into the framebuffer. you probably dont want to disable it - i doubt if youd see much at all afterward if you did - but you can just run `clear` before your motd or put `<ESC>[2J` at the head of your message.

Comment: Can I somehow run `clear` before text from `/etc/issue` is displayed?
I.e. I'd like to disable showing-the-text-from-subject not the mapping itself.

Comment: of course. just figure out what prints your issue deal, then do `clear`  just beforehand.

Comment: Hint: you can probably start in `/etc` and whatever config file you use to train your `getty`.